# Directory changes in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, directory

I was reading Ubuntu Linux Unleashed 2021 by Matthew Helmke and found the location of many configuration files/directories  mentioned on the book has been moved or changed drastically.Why is that and where can I find the changes made to listing of the directory structure on Ubuntu 22.04 and where they were on other versions before ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you give some examples of the differences?  /etc has been the location for system configs forever, but the user home hidden dirs .config, .local, .cache, ... contain application specific configs -- which is why a mounted /home is a terrible idea if you try to share it among different releases/distributions. Better just share your data with a specific mounted data dir.

Comment: "*Why is that...?*" Locations change because the developers or packagers change them for a variety of good reasons. Redesign, conflicts, standards, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to sound vague, but there are various reasons why the location of configuration files/directories would get moved or changed. It is mainly due to software updates in different Ubuntu releases.

It would be more practical (And less painful) to consult the man page for the configuration file(s) of the command-line program you are using, Than to get a listing of changes done between different Ubuntu releases.

The configuration files of a command-line program are listed in the man page, which is specific to the Ubuntu release you are using.

Just for example:

`man mount`

/etc/fstab is a configuration file for the `mount` command.

There is a man page also for /etc/fstab

`man fstab`